# Records processed metric for intermediate datasets

Tags: apache-spark

I have created a spark job using DATASET API. There is chain of operations performed until the final result which is collected on HDFS.

But I also need to know how many records were read for each intermediate dataset. Lets say I apply 5 operations on dataset (could be map, groupby etc), I need to know how many records were there for each of 5 intermediate dataset. Can anybody suggest how this can be obtained at dataset level. I guess I can find this out at task level (using listeners) but not sure how to get it at dataset level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The nearest from Spark documentation related to metrics is [Accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators). However this is good only for actions and they mentioned that acucmulators will not be updated for transformations.

You can still use count to get the latest counts after each operation. But should keep in mind that its an extra step like any other and you need to see if the ingestion should be done faster with less metrics or slower with all metrics.

Now coming back to listerners, I see that a SparkListener can receive events about when applications, jobs, stages, and tasks start and complete as well as other infrastructure-centric events like drivers being added or removed, when an RDD is unpersisted, or when environment properties change. All the information you can find about the health of Spark applications and the entire infrastructure is in the WebUI.

Your requirement is more of a custom implementation. Not sure if you can achieve this. Some info regarding exporting metrics is [here](http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/27/monitoring-spark-with-graphite-and-grafana/).

All metrics which you can collect are at job start, job end, task start and task end. You can check the docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html)

Hope the above info might guide you in finding a better solutions